# Accessing domain via www. redirects to subdomain

Tags: redirect, apache2, subdomain, virtual, hosts

I have an issue with our website. When accessed via https://website.com all works fine, but accessing it through www.website.com it redirects to the subdomain.

Primary domain virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerAdmin contact@website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com

<Directory /var/www/html/website/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName hwebsite.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/

ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/website.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private-key.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/website.com.ca-bundle
 <Directory /var/www/html/website/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Subdomain virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin contact@website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomains/sub.website.com/
ServerName sub.website.com
ServerAlias www.sub.website.com

<Directory /var/www/subdomains/sub.website.com/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName sub.website.com
ServerAlias www.sub.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomains/sub.website.com/

ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.website.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/sub.website.com.key
<Directory /var/www/subdomains/sub.website.com/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If anybody can shed some light, it would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Cristi Enache